# Prevent UIButton from responding to touchesBegan Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a "Start Game" button that starts the game, but I don't want it to respond to touchesBegan. I only want my game to detect touchesBegan when I tap the screen after the start button is pressed. Could anyone help?

Comment: Could you please post the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: Have you bound the button touchupinside to some IBAction?